# ACTIVE DIRECTORY,EXCHANGE, SHAREPOINT via REST

Tags: web-services, rest, active-directory, ldap, pega

Hello everyone  I'm trying to retrieve a user data from Active Directory, like Names, departments they belong to etc., and send all that info to a client via REST how can I achieve this?

Also I have a sharepoint application that retrieves part of this info from the AD and is connected via LDAP.

Now what would be the best way to direct all this info to the client via web services I woul prefer REST since is out of the box.

I'm using
Exchange Server 2010 version 14.02.0247.005 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: are you using Pega? If yes, use connector RULE.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for on-prem Exchange?  If so you can use EWS or Powershell.  Unfortunately, the only REST services I know of for Exchange are for Office 365.

Here's an overview on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877024%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) for Exchange 2010 dev.